# CSS padding and width issue

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

So I'm trying to give conditional render div a width of full, but bcz I've given padding to its parent it's not taking the full width of the container

here is the code:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import DoubleTickIcon from "../PersonalChatAssets/DoubleTick.png";
import SingleTickIcon from "../PersonalChatAssets/SingleTick.png";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
interface textbody {
  content: string;
  sent: boolean;
  time: string;
  replyReference: any;
}

const TextMessage = (props: textbody) => {
  console.log("Referece::::", props.replyReference);
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-end w-[332px] ml-[52px] mr-[20px] mb-[18px]">
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
        <Image src={props.sent ? DoubleTickIcon : SingleTickIcon} alt="" />
        <h1 className="font-normal text-[12px] mb-0 font-[#787580]">
          {props.time}
        </h1>
      </div>

//this is its parent
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-[#F7CA16] rounded-l-[16px] pr-[14px] pl-[14px] pt-[8px] pb-[8px] font-inter font-[14px] rounded-b-[16px] min-h-[40px] max-w-[340px] min-w-[60px] break-words">

//This is Conditional rendring part 
        {props.replyReference?.message !== undefined && (
          <div className="h-[52px] reply-gradient p-2 ">  
            <div className="-space-y-3 overflow-ellipsis truncate border-l-[4px] border-solid border-[#1F1D25] pl-2">
              <h1 className="">to {props.replyReference?.author}</h1>
              <p className="max-w-[230px] truncate ">
                {props.replyReference?.message}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

        <h1 className="flex justify-center item-center w-full h-full mb-0">{props.content}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextMessage;
```

This is the output I'm getting now:

[image: this is the output I'm getting now]

This is the output I want:

[image: This is the output I want]

Answer (score 0):

You should move `pr-[14px] pl-[14px] pt-[8px] pb-[8px]` to `reply-gradient` and `h1` elements.

Similarly, you also need to add `rounded-l-[16px] rounded-b-[0]` to `reply-gradient` to have the same border styles with the parent component.

```
import Image from "next/image";
import DoubleTickIcon from "../PersonalChatAssets/DoubleTick.png";
import SingleTickIcon from "../PersonalChatAssets/SingleTick.png";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
interface textbody {
  content: string;
  sent: boolean;
  time: string;
  replyReference: any;
}

const TextMessage = (props: textbody) => {
  console.log("Referece::::", props.replyReference);
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-end w-[332px] ml-[52px] mr-[20px] mb-[18px]">
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
        <Image src={props.sent ? DoubleTickIcon : SingleTickIcon} alt="" />
        <h1 className="font-normal text-[12px] mb-0 font-[#787580]">
          {props.time}
        </h1>
      </div>

//this is its parent
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-[#F7CA16] rounded-l-[16px] font-inter font-[14px] rounded-b-[16px] min-h-[40px] max-w-[340px] min-w-[60px] break-words">

//This is Conditional rendring part 
        {props.replyReference?.message !== undefined && (
          <div className="h-[52px] reply-gradient p-2 pr-[14px] pl-[14px] pt-[8px] pb-[8px] rounded-l-[16px] rounded-b-[0]">  
            <div className="-space-y-3 overflow-ellipsis truncate border-l-[4px] border-solid border-[#1F1D25] pl-2">
              <h1 className="">to {props.replyReference?.author}</h1>
              <p className="max-w-[230px] truncate ">
                {props.replyReference?.message}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

        <h1 className="flex justify-center item-center w-full h-full mb-0 pr-[14px] pl-[14px] pt-[8px] pb-[8px]">{props.content}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextMessage;
```

You can check [this playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/iyFem58NAk)

Comment: I've tried this, but it was only changing the shape of inner div, not overcoming the gap coming from parent div in terms of padding.

Comment: Could you screenshot and share what it looks like right now? It's hard to guess from non-runnable code @AbdulHaseeb

Comment: by the way, I just modified my answer and added the playground https://play.tailwindcss.com/iyFem58NAk. You can check it out. @AbdulHaseeb

Comment: You're welcome!~ By the way, if you think it's helpful, please mark my answer as your solution. That will give me as well as our community a little support, bro @AbdulHaseeb :D